# PDO - Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I searched similar issues here but could not fix my problem.

I'm trying to add a search function to my website, but for some reason the search results are not displayed. In my error_log I get this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function prepare() on null in /home/..../search.php on line 9

which is this line:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM subs WHERE sub_title LIKE '%$search%' LIMIT 0, 10");
```

Here is my search.php code:

```
<?php
require_once('includes/config.php'); 
include("includes/header.php");

// Search from MySQL database table
$search = $_POST['search'];
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM subs WHERE sub_title LIKE '%$search%' LIMIT 0, 10");
$query->bindValue(1, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();

// Display search result 
if(!$query->rowCount() == 0) {
echo "Search found:<br>";
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><td>Title</td><td>Category></td><td>Language</td><td>Time</td><td>Download</td></tr>";
while($results = $query->fetch()) {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $results['sub_title'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $results['category'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $results['sub_lang'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $results['timestamp'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $results['sub_data'];
    echo "</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
} else {
echo "Nothing found";
}

?>
```

Here is my config.php

```
<?php 
$username = '------';
$password = '------';

try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=-----', $username, $password, array(
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
));
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
echo "Failed to connect to database!" . "<br><br>";
echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

and here is my search form which is in the header.php

```
<form class="form-inline" action="search.php" method="POST">
     <input class="form-control" name="search" id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search">
 </form>
```

Comment: I thik you probaly intended to use $conn instead of $pdo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're using: `$query = $pdo->prepare`

It should be:

`$query = $conn->prepare()`

Because I am a lazy coder I made a new class to save a bit of time:

```
class DBCommon
{
    private $conn;

    /** @var Common */
    public $common;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $database = new Database();
        $db = $database->dbConnection();
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    public function runQuery($sql)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        return $stmt;
    }
}
```